# Need help to bulk download logs from Google Cloud Platform - Cloud Logging

Tags: java, logging, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I am new to GCP. I want to download logs from GCP Cloud Logging. Currently I am using **google-cloud-logging** library in java and fetching all the logs page by page. But it is really slow because of the API calls. Is there a better way to download bulk logs from GCP Cloud Logging by applying filters.

I am currently using this library.

```
<groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>google-cloud-logging</artifactId>
<version>1.101.2</version>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe look at the gcloud logging read command line tool ...

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Kolban . I am currently using this [https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/cloud-client-libraries). I cannot see much difference in using CLI compare to Java library.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood?  I thought the puzzle was to get all records without having to work with paging.  It seems that the gcloud command tool gets all log entries (unless `--limit`) is supplied.

If I may ask, why do you want to download all log entries?  Maybe create a sink to Google Cloud Storage such that all new log entries that you are interested in are always permanently recorded?

Comment: Thanks again for the reply @Kolban . I think you got it right. I was also expecting the same. I tried using Cloud-SDK CLI. It works fine without pagination. Thanks. To answer your question, the reason for downloading logs to another machine is for remote debugging.

Comment: @pi-N - did previous comment solve your question or are you still looking for a solution ?

Comment: @W_B I followed the given link and solved the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can download all the existing logs using the `gcloud logging read` command.  This returns all (matched) log entries without any form of paging/pagination.  We can read about this command in detail here:

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/read

For future log entries, consider using a Logging sink to capture the desired log entries automatically.  Destinations of a sink include Google Cloud Storage and BigQuery.

Comment: Although the documentation say the default i "unlimited" I **don't** get all my logs. The difficulty of getting just a couple of days of logs downloaded for local processing is a major pain with GCP. This was the situations last year, and AFAICS it's not better now. Good luck with this: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/routing/copy-logs#get-location